# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException - multi-threaded server

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

We are trying to implement a multi-threaded server client application (an online market place application) ,the output is supposed to be stored in a file.We keep getting this error (NullPointerException).It's our first time to use Java sockets.We have checked all the answers posted but none helped us.

**This is the error that we get :**

```
 nopefailed
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at marketplace.create_account.createActionPerformed(create_account.java:198)
    at marketplace.create_account.access$400(create_account.java:21)
    at marketplace.create_account$5.actionPerformed(create_account.java:103)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**Server Code :**

```
package marketplace;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class server extends javax.swing.JFrame {
ServerSocket server;
 public void listenSocket(){
  try{
      server = new ServerSocket(4444);
      Socket cli=server.accept();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Could not listen on port 4444");
    System.exit(-1);
  }
  while(true){
    ClientWorker ca;

    try{
//server.accept returns a client connection 
    Socket cli=server.accept();
      ca = new ClientWorker(cli);
      Thread t = new Thread(ca);
      t.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // System.out.println("Accept failed: 4444");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
}
  public server() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Server");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(168, 168, 168)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(200, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(179, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new server().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
 protected void finalize(){

     try{
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not close socket");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
  }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
class ClientWorker implements Runnable {
  private Socket client;
 // private JTextArea textArea;

//Constructor
  ClientWorker(Socket client) {
    this.client = client;

  }

  @Override
  public void run(){
    String line;
    BufferedReader in = null ;
    PrintWriter writer = null ;
    try{
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

      writer =  new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("in or out failed");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    while(true){
      try{
        line = in.readLine();

        writer.println(line);

       }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Read failed");
        System.exit(-1);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

**client code**

```
package marketplace;

//import static com.sun.glass.ui.Cursor.setVisible;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import  java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

class create_account extends javax.swing.JFrame  {
   Socket socket;PrintWriter out; BufferedReader in;
public void listenSocket(){
//Create socket connection
   try{
       socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
       out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
       in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     System.out.println("Unknown host");
     System.exit(1);
   } catch  (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("No I/O");
     System.exit(1);
   }
}
 public create_account() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        password = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        lastname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        firstname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        create = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("username");

        jLabel2.setText("password");

        username.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                usernameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        password.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                passwordActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lastname.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                lastnameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("First name");

        jLabel4.setText("Last name");

        firstname.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                firstnameActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        create.setText("Create account");
        create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                createActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 62, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(username)
                            .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 62, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(firstname)
                            .addComponent(lastname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                        .addComponent(create)))
                .addContainerGap(130, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(firstname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(lastname, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(3, 3, 3)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(create)
                .addContainerGap(123, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void usernameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    }                                        

    private void passwordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    }                                        

    private void lastnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void firstnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
 try{
       socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
       out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
       in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));



} 
 catch ( IOException e) {
    System.out.println("nopefailed");
}


 while(true){

      String fname = firstname.getText();
     out.println(fname);

     String lname = lastname.getText();
     out.println(lname);
     String pass = password.getText();
     out.println(pass);
     String user = username.getText();
     out.println(user);
     }




    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(create_account.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(create_account.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(create_account.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(create_account.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new create_account().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton create;
    public javax.swing.JTextField firstname;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    public javax.swing.JTextField lastname;
    public javax.swing.JTextField password;
    public javax.swing.JTextField username;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: We are using Netbeans

Comment: `System.out.println("nopefailed");` ← Instead of that, your catch block should contain `e.printStackTrace();`.  The next line in the catch block should be `System.exit(2);`, because your application cannot possibly work if you weren’t able to create the socket, so there is no point in continuing.